# Как записать данные в переменную byte[] byteArray

Tags: java

так пишет что неправильно

```
   byte[] byteArray = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы записать данные в массив с вашими значениями, нужно их оформить не квадратными, а фигурными скобками:

```
byte[] byteArray = {104, 101, 108, 108, 111};
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала мы должный проинициализировать переменную:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[5];
```

После - заполнить по принципу

```
byteArray[0] = 3;
byteArray[1] = -4;
```

Также мы можем заполнить массив стандартными значениями при инициализации:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[]{104, 101, 108, 108, 111};
```

Comment: Не обязательно делать так много шагов, но ответ верный